# Services does not contain a definition for AddCors for solve Cross site origin problem in WASM

Tags: c#, cors, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I want to get some data from a `web api`, and I write this code:

```
var response = await Client.GetAsync("https://SomeURL/Action");
```

when I run this code in button click I get this error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://SomeURL/Action' from origin 'http://OtherURL' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

so for solve this problem I was trying to add this code in `program.cs` in `Blazor` application:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://SomeURL/")
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowCredentials()
           .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));
});
```

[image]

but `Services` does not contain a definition for `AddCors`. How can I solve this issue? Thanks

---

**Edit 1)**

I create very simple built-in web api:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
```

and I get the result:

[image]

When I want to connect to this web api I get `CORS` error. and I change  `program.cs` in **Web API** project:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => 
               builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5179")
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowCredentials()
       .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

and in `Blazor` project I have this:

```
@page "/counter"
@inject HttpClient Client

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;

        var response = await Client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7229/weatherforecast");
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi there! have you tried app.UseCors(... after adding them to the services

Comment: @spzvtbg there is no `app` in `program.cs`

Comment: so when the builder is build give an IApplicationBuilder back that is Runned due his Run method. Store it in variable and use it

Comment: You are adding cors to the server project? Not the WASM client?

Comment: In the browser can you show the outgoing request in the developers tools. You are injecting a html client that should already have a base address, this is an issue I suspect.

Comment: `ctrl` + `;` is what you need

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works for me:

add `app.UseCors();` with policy name this way:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

app.UseAuthorization();
```